# Can you interleave multiple values when joining columns in OpenRefine?

Tags: openrefine

I have a table of two columns where each cell has multiple values separated by a new-line. The values across the two columns are aligned. I would like to merge the values of the two columns in to a new column where the values of the first lines are merged before the values of the second line.

Something like this:

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 | New Column |
|----------|----------|------------|
|A         |B         |A (B)       |
|C         |D         |C (D)       |
|----------|----------|------------|
|E         |F         |E (F)       |
|G         |H         |G (H)       |
```

I tried both joining and adding a column based on values from columns but I can only merge in order so it ends up like this:

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 | New Column |
|----------|----------|------------|
|A         |B         |A           |
|C         |D         |C           |
|          |          |B           |
|          |          |D           |
|----------|----------|------------|
|E         |F         |E           |
|G         |H         |G           |
|          |          |F           |
|          |          |H           |
|----------|----------|------------|
```

I can get a manual individual answer like this:

```
cells["Column 1"].value.split("\n")[0] + " (" + cells["Column 2"].value.split("\n")[0] + ")"
```

Is there a way to iterate though the arrays? I have tried using forEach but only get errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use records and cell splitting for the required transformation:

1. Add new column "Index" via "Edit column => Add column based on this column..." and the GREL expression `rowIndex`. We need this column to restore the original rows after modifying them.
2. Move the new column "Index" to the beginning via "Edit column => Move column to beginning".
3. Change into [records mode](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/exploring#rows-vs-records).
4. On "Column 1" split the cells on whitespace via "Edit column => Split multi-valued cells" using `\n` as separator and activating the "regular expression" checkbox.
5. Repeat the last step on "Column 2".
6. Add the new column using the expression `row.cells["Column 1"].value + " (" + row.cells["Column 2"].value + ")"`
7. Undo the cell splitting on via "Edit cells => Join multi-valued cells".
   Note that if you use `\n` it will literally insert "\n" as separator.
   So I usually use a custom separator like `|` and then replace it
   with `\n` in a separate step.
8. Delete remaining columns (like "Index").